# Crontab with delete before sync

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

I have a question, i build on this moment a loadbalancer server with 2 servers. Now i have the sync with crontab.

But if i delete a file or directory on server 1 than stay the file on server 2. and if i delete a file or directory on server 2 than stay the file on server 1.

This my crontab from server 1

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
*/1 * * * * date >> /var/log/rsync_log
*/1 * * * * rsync -avrhe --delete-before 'ssh -p SSHPORTNUMBER' USERNAME@IPTOSERVER2:/home/ploi/ /home/ploi/ >> /var/log/rsync_log
```

This my crontab from Server 2

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
*/1 * * * * date >> /var/log/rsync_log
*/1 * * * * rsync -avrhe --delete-before 'ssh -p SSHPORTNUMBER' /home/ploi/ USERNAME@IPSERVER1:/home/ploi/ >> /var/log/rsync_log
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Willem

Comment: You need a dedicated sync application, I don't think `rsync` can implement this kind of two-2ay synchronization with deletions.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a shell script , which write delete command, and use crontab to exec it;
when you want to delete a file, you just write command to this sh file, sh file will sync to other server, then use crontab to exec this sh file to delete the real file.